# MT4/5, Multicharts or Interactive Brokers API for Forex Automated Trading?

Tags: c++, api, expert-system, algorithmic-trading, forex

I've been very interested in algorithmic trading in Forex and I'm not sure where to start.

I would prefer to use C++, so I was looking into Interactive Brokers C++ API but I'm not sure it would be a good idea to lock myself to Interactive Brokers.

Would it be better to use Multicharts or MT4/MT4 and go through learning and using their programming language or should I stick with C++/Interactive Brokers? What are some disadvantages to each?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an API, you need to get into FIX http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/. These days all the major banks and brokerages speak FIX. If you want C++ then use http://www.quickfixengine.org/ (or you can use Java or other) to capture your market data, do your analysis, submit your orders, and manage your risk with the bank or broker you choose.

That is unless you want charts based API stuff. For that, IB seems to be a good place to start although, as you say, a lot of people use MT4.

Comment: What's the advantage of using FIX over just programming for MT4 or using IB C++ API, etc.?

Also would it be a good idea to program in MT4, see if I can actually get anything working, then move on to FIX instead of starting off with FIX without any experience with Forex or trading in general?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you are going to get into technical analysis then you need something like IB or MT4. But if you simply need to send FX orders to banks or brokers, then use FIX, because that's where the industry is at.